# Asymptotic for $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z} }\frac{1}{(a|k|+b)^{1+c}} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

recently I stumbled more than once on sums of the following form

$$
\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z} }\frac{1}{(a|k|+b)^{1+c}} 
$$
where $a,b,c>0$ real numbers. One can prove that this always converges, and I suppose you can try to relate it to zeta functions.

However, I would like to estimate the sum in terms of $a$ and $b$ and $c$. More particularly, I would like to know the order of the sum as $b \longrightarrow \infty$.

I tried to use integral aproximations, but they seemed to loose a lot of informations as I take $b$ large.

Comment: Approximating with an integral does lose information, but it's strong enough to show that $$\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z} }\frac{1}{(a|k|+b)^{1+c}} = \frac{2}{acb^c} + O\!\left(\frac{1}{b^{1+c}}\right).$$ Could you clarify how much more information you'd like?

Comment: Hi, I was also looking for 
$$
 c_1 \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z} }\frac{1}{(a|k|)^{1+c}+b^{1+c}}  \le\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z} }\frac{1}{(a|k|+b)^{1+c}}  \le c_2
\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z} }\frac{1}{(a|k|)^{1+c}+b^{1+c}} 
$$
Which I now found out is trivial. But I did not manage to get the same asymptotics as you, would you mind showing your calculations? Thank you very much.